# Expected Value on code

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, computer-science, computational-complexity

I'm trying to figure out the expected number of times this algorithm will print. I'm stuck on how to go about doing so. I used an indicator variable to keep track of the number of print statements being printed, but I'm stumped on the meat part of it.

random(X,Y,Z):

print(X)
  if Y != X:
      print(Y)
  if Z != Y and Z != X:
      print(Z)
You will suppose the inputs X,Y,Z are chosen at random, uniformly and independently from the set {1,...,k}, (for some k being >=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, the code is printing the distinct elements of the given 3 input set.

The number of times 1 print happens = $k$ (all 3 inputs are the same).

The number of times 2 prints happens = $3k(k-1)$ (two of the inputs are the same).

The number of times 3 prints happens = $k(k-1)(k-2)$ (all the three inputs are different).

So, the expected number of times this algorithm will print would be

$\frac{1\times k + 2\times 3k(k-1)+ 3 \times k(k-1)(k-2)}{k^3}$ = $\frac{1+3k(k-1)}{k^2}$

Comment: How do you get 3k(k-1) for two inputs? and whats the intuition behind 1*k+2*..../k^3?

Comment: For the two distinct case, pick one element (which is $k$ ways) and repeat it twice. Pick the second element (which is $k-1$ ways) and place it either to the left, middle or right of the repeated first element. So, it is $3k(k-1)$.

Comment: Expected value of any discrete random variable is the average of the random variable, i.e., $\sum_i a_i p_i$ where $p_i$ is the probability of the random variable taking the value $a_i$. In your question, the possible outcomes are $1, 2$ and $3$. And the probability of the outcome 1 is $k/k^3$, outcome 2 is $3k(k-1)/k^3$ etc.